# Conflict with prototype javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototypejs

I have javascript calendar appears when the user click on a text box and I must call the prototype.js from the following link in-order to allow the calendar to work
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js

The calendar works fine but I found that all the other javascripts in my page stopped working!

Any suggestions?

Comment: "all the other javascripts in my page stopped working" - is there a particular code snippet you can share that stopped working? Perhaps there is a conflict with prototype?

Comment: need more details about calandar..what library does it use? Create catalog of all script tags used in page. We have no idea what you are using and whether adding prototype caused problem, or adding something else caused problem

Comment: I'm using this calendar "calendarview.org"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be when you want to use two and more different libraries on one page. In that case the libraries goes in conflict, when the same function names exist in all libs at the same scope. In this cases the last function implementation will be used.

For example, you implement some function `fn()` in the global scope and after that implementation you insert some library that also implement the function `fn()` in the same scope. The second function reimplement the first and by each call of the `fn()` the browser will use the second implementation instead of your.

Comment: Yea, I really found that.. :)